# unique link visits

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count unique user visits (user x visit link A 20 times and link B 5 times count 2) grouped by quarter and year
This is the table:

| id | user_id | link | added_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | link1 | - |
| 2 | 10 | link1 | - |
| 3 | 10 | link1 | - |
| 4 | 10 | link2 | - |
| 5 | 10 | link2 | - |
| 6 | 10 | link2 | - |
| 7 | 10 | link7 | - |
| 8 | 10 | link5 | - |
| 9 | 11 | link5 | - |
| 10 | 11 | link5 | - |
| 11 | 11 | link5 | - |
| 12 | 11 | link5 | - |

So far my query looks like this

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(QUARTER(added_on)," ",YEAR(added_on)) AS quarter_year
FROM table
GROUP BY YEAR(added_on), QUARTER(added_on)
ORDER BY added_on DESC
```

Comment: Expand GROUP BY expression, add needed columns (user and link). And add COUNT().

Comment: Is there any other way to do it in the select without changeing group by ? @Akina

Comment: No. If you need to count visits per **user** per **link** per **year/quarter** then you must group by **user**, **link** and **year/quarter**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the number of visits per user per link use this query.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(QUARTER(added_on)," ",YEAR(added_on)) AS quarter_year,
  user_id,
  link,
  count(id) as number_of_visits
FROM t
GROUP BY 
  1,
  user_id,
  link
ORDER BY 
  1 DESC,
  user_id;
```

If you want the number of different links visited by the user then use the following query.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(QUARTER(added_on)," ",YEAR(added_on)) AS quarter_year,
  user_id,
  count(distinct link) as number_of_links
FROM t
GROUP BY 
  1,
  user_id
ORDER BY 
  1 DESC,
  user_id;
```

If you want the number of distinct visits (user - link) per quarter
then use this query:

```
select
  quarter_year,
  sum(number_of_links) as distinct_visits
from (
SELECT 
  CONCAT(QUARTER(added_on)," ",YEAR(added_on)) AS quarter_year,
  user_id,
  count(distinct link) as number_of_links
FROM t
GROUP BY 
  1,
  user_id
ORDER BY 
  1 DESC,
  user_id) q
group by quarter_year
order by quarter_year;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1dc77a6dbd667179d41b332bfc4e8dd7)*

Comment: I would like to keep GROUP BY with YEAR(added_on), 
  QUARTER(added_on), it there any way to make it with group by like that?

Comment: Please could you explain in other words your need? If user a had visited link1 twice and link2 twice does that count as 2 distinct visits?

Comment: Yes it count as 2, but I need to keep group by as it is